# Number Guessing Game using while loop

Tags: javascript

In this project, I need to set a maximum of 10 guesses, an indication of what number is being guessed and keep those results on the screen at the end of each game without overwrite the previous guesses.

Each set of guess output needs to be numbered to indicate how many guesses have been made. For the output, I need to use innerHTML. The user will guess a number from 1 to 999. I have to use while loop.

So far this is the code where I'm working and I have some errors and it's not working. Can anybody put me in the right direction to finish this code?

The errors that I found when I inspect the document are checkGuess() function and an anonymous function with a message "Cannot read property 'value' of null"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var guesses = document.getElementById("guesses");
    var lastResult = document.getElementById("lastResult");
    var lowOrHi = document.getElementById("lowOrHi");
    var guessSubmit = document.getElementById("guessSubmit");
    var guessField = document.getElementById("guessField");
    var guessCount = 1;

    function checkGuess() {
        var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
        guesses.innerHTML += userGuess + "";
    }

    while (guessCount == 10) {
        lastResult.innerHTML = "!!!GAME OVER!!!";
        disableForm();
    } else {

        if (userGuess == randomNumber) {
            lastResult.innerHTML = "Congratulations! You got it right!";
            lowOrHi.innerHTML = "";
            disableForm();
        } else {
            lastResult.innerHTML = "Wrong!";
            if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
                lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too low!";
            } else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
                lowOrHi.innerHTML = "Your guess is too high!";
            }
        }
        guessCount++;
        guessField.value = "";
    }
    }

    function disableForm() {
        var wholeForm = document.querySelector(".form"); // grab a reference to the whole form (the contents of the div with class form)
        wholeForm.style.opacity = 0.5; // change the opacity of the form to 0.5
        guessField.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        guessSubmit.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled"); // disable the form field and submit button so they can no longer be used
    }
    guessSubmit.onclick = checkGuess;
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Number guessing game</h1>
    <p id="guesses"></p>
    <p id="lastResult"></p>
    <p id="lowOrHi"></p>

    <div class="form">
        <label for="guessField">Enter your next guess: </label>
        <input type="text" id="guessField">
        <button id="guessSubmit">Enter Guess</button>
    </div>

    <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: What are the errors and what's not working?

Comment: One the errors that I can not solve is this:function checkGuess()
{
  var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
  guesses.innerHTML += userGuess + "";
}

Comment: Another error is an anonymous function checkGuess();

Answer (score 0):

Your program is all wrong and is actually doing nothing

the only thing that actually executes is everything outside your functions, 
and those are being called only when the page is loaded for first time

in order to execute your CheckGuess you need to actually call it :

```
 <button id="guessSubmit" onclick="checkGuess() ">Enter Guess</button>
```

but everything else that is actually outside of your functions are only executed when the page is loading

also you have a while--else statement, that's not even possible 
then again... it is outside a function so it is useless

You need to put everything on one single statement 
YOU DO NOT NEED A WHILE 
once you write something down on the page it will stay there until it reloads 
if you write a while like that you will just loop your code endless.

this code and logic is so wrong in so many ways i will sent you a functional code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var guesscount =0;
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;  

    function checkGuess() 
    {
        guesscount = guesscount  +1;
        var userGuess = document.getElementById("guessField").value;
        document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += Number(userGuess)+ '<br>';
        CheckResults();    


    }

    function CheckResults()
    {
        //add here your logics if the number is wrong
        if ( guesscount>= 10)
        {
             document.getElementById("guessField").disabled = true;
             document.getElementById("guessSubmit").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
             document.getElementById('guesses').innerHTML += 'game Over !';
        }
    }

</script>


</head>

<body>
    <h1>Number guessing game</h1>
    <label id="guesses"></label>
    <label id="lastResult"></label>
    <label id="lowOrHi"></label>

    <div class="form">
        <label for="guessField">Enter your next guess: </label>
        <input type="text" id="guessField">
        <button id="guessSubmit" onclick="checkGuess() ">Enter Guess</button>
    </div>

    <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: user3692679, do you think that if I use for or do-while loops, any of those, can help to do a better coding and accomplish my goal?

Comment: no, this is a web based application, 
you don't need whiles to keep the progam working like a console application.

Comment: the code above is almost half of your application, you just need to compare the next result , whiles for this is a no-no 
not useful, not needed